# What exactly is the difference between the Dreamhost IDE and Netbeans?

Tags: ide, netbeans, dreamhost

I just started using Netbeans about a week ago, and really like it thus far.  Now I'm seeing something about Dreamhost IDE which I guess is a program that is built using the Netbeans platform.  I use Dreamhost as the hosting company for many of my projects.  What is the benefit of using Dreamhost IDE over Netbeans?  Documentation on the software is non-existent from what I can tell (not even a mention in the Dreamhost wiki).  All I was able to find was a short description of what it was on a Sourceforge download page, and I found a short silent video on YouTube demoing it.  So I guess I'm asking, what features is it bringing to the table, and what is the difference between it and Netbeans?

The description on the Sourceforge page is as follows (typos retained)...

> DreamHost IDE is php and ruby integrated development environment built on NetBeans IDE and provides easy deploy of your applications to the DreamHost services. Also provides you an easy eay hew to setup these services.

Maybe the answer is in the description, and I just don't comprehend it?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw a video demo, and when you start the program, you can Login to the Dreamhost services. It remembers your Project and settings (ftp connections, database connections). If I understood, you can work from the cloud (the program is not in the could, but your project and settings are).